# jquery ui tabs, intercept default ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to be able to modify the url in the anchors for the tabs and add some query params.  Most examples floating around the net suggest that I use code like

```
            $('#tabs-left').tabs({
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //do some mods here
                return true;
            }
        }).removeClass("ui-corner-all");
```

My problem is the select event only fires when selecting a new tab, and so I cannot trap the content that is loaded into the default tab.

What can I use to trap the loading of the content via ajax ?   I see there is a load event, but that only fires after the content is loaded, which is too late.
I read in some bug fix that a beforeload event is planned for a future release, but I need something that works now.  I am using jquery-ui-1.8.21

Can anyone suggest a way forward ?

Thanks,

Steed.